# Getting an endless loop somewhere

Tags: python

I need some help with this program I am trying to finish. This thing is kind of a mess. its the end of a 12 hour day and it's due tonight and I think I'm just making things worse at this point. I'm struggling with implementing input of "4" for the player_choice and getting the program to just say 'Exiting the program' and stop. When I input a choice currently, I get what I think is an endless loop because the entire IDE locks up and crashes.

program requirements:

```
1) Get and return the value of the computer’s choice as an integer.  
2) Use a menu to get, validate, and return the player’s choices.  
The player will enter their menu choice for rock, paper, scissors, or quit.  
Validate the choice before returning it.
3) Determine the winner.  There are a total of 9 possible combinations of
computer and player choices.  The menu should always be displayed after the outcome has 
been displayed regardless of the outcome 
(i.e. ties should be treated the same as any other outcome). 
4) After the player chooses to stop playing, display the total number of
 games that ended in a tie, the total number the computer won, and the total
 number the player won.
```

Here is the program code:

```
import random

def main():
    display_menu()   
    print('There were', number_of_tied_games, 'tie games played.')
    print('The computer won', number_of_computer_games, 'game(s).')
    print('You won', number_of_player_games, 'game(s).')

def process_computer_choice():
    choice1 = random.randint(1,3)
    return choice1

def process_player_choice():
    print('What is your choice?')
    choice2 = (input())
    while choice2 != "1" and choice2 != "2" and choice2 != "3" and choice2 != "4":
        print("ERROR: the choice can only be 1, 2, 3, or 4.")
        choice2 = (input("Please enter a correct choice: ")) 
    return choice2

def determine_winner(player_choice, computer_choice, choice2):
    while choice2 != "4":
        if computer_choice == 1:
            if player_choice == "2":
                print('Paper covers rock. You win!')
                winner = 'player'
            elif player_choice == "3":
                print("Rock crushes scissors. The computer wins!")
                winner = 'computer'
            else:
                print('The game is tied. Try again.')
                winner = 'tied'
        if computer_choice == 2:
            if player_choice == "1":
                print('Paper covers rock. The computer wins!')
                winner = 'computer'
            elif player_choice == "3":
                print("Scissors cuts paper. You win!")
                winner = 'player'
            else:
                print('The game is tied. Try again.')
                winner = 'tied'
        if computer_choice == 3:
            if player_choice == "1":
                print('Rock smashes scissors. You win!')
                winner = 'player'
            elif player_choice == "2":
                print("Scissors cuts paper. The computer wins!")
                winner = 'computer'
            else:
                print('The game is tied. Try again.')
                winner = 'tied'
    return winner

def display_menu(): 
    choice2 = 0
    number_of_tied_games = 0
    number_of_player_games = 0
    number_of_computer_games = 0   

    print('        MENU')
    print('1) Rock')
    print('2) Paper')
    print('3) Scissors')
    print('4) Quit')
    print("Let's play the game of Rock, Paper, Scissors.")
    computer_choice = process_computer_choice()
    player_choice = process_player_choice()    
    while choice2 != "4":

        if computer_choice == 1:
            print('The computer chooses rock.')
        elif computer_choice == 2:
            print('The computer chooses paper.')
        else:
            print('The computer chooses scissors.')
        #display player choice
        if player_choice == "1":
            print('You choose rock.')
        elif player_choice == "2":
            print('You choose paper.')
        else:
            print('You choose scissors.')

        result = determine_winner(player_choice, computer_choice, choice2)
        if result == 'computer':
            number_of_computer_games += 1
        elif result == 'player':
            number_of_player_games += 1
        else:
            number_of_tied_games += 1
        print    


main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is related to the `determine_winner` method.
The code inside the method will run while the value of `choice2` isn't 4, but you don't change it during the loop, therefore it won't stop looping.

There are several solutions to this issue, the easiest is simply to not use a loop (after all, you should check the result only once every game played).

```
def determine_winner(player_choice, computer_choice, choice2):
    if computer_choice == 1:
        if player_choice == "2":
            print('Paper covers rock. You win!')
            winner = 'player'
        elif player_choice == "3":
            print("Rock crushes scissors. The computer wins!")
            winner = 'computer'
        else:
            print('The game is tied. Try again.')
            winner = 'tied'
    if computer_choice == 2:
        if player_choice == "1":
            print('Paper covers rock. The computer wins!')
            winner = 'computer'
        elif player_choice == "3":
            print("Scissors cuts paper. You win!")
            winner = 'player'
        else:
            print('The game is tied. Try again.')
            winner = 'tied'
    if computer_choice == 3:
        if player_choice == "1":
            print('Rock smashes scissors. You win!')
            winner = 'player'
        elif player_choice == "2":
            print("Scissors cuts paper. The computer wins!")
            winner = 'computer'
        else:
            print('The game is tied. Try again.')
            winner = 'tied'
    return winner
```

That said, there are other errors that you should fix:

- The loop location is wrong. You should display the menu and get the data every time the a match ends. (@line75)
- You have added the choice2 variable but you never changed it. I believe it should be `player_choice` instead. (@lines 62~74)
- By removing the `choice2` variable, you don't need to pass it to the determine_winner method.
- Remember that the "number_of_*_games" variables should declared on the global escope and later on global, otherwise you won't be able to access them later on main() method.

The full complete code is:

```
import random

tied_games = 0
player_games = 0
computer_games = 0

def main():
    display_menu()
    print('There were', tied_games, 'tie games played.')
    print('The computer won', computer_games, 'game(s).')
    print('You won', player_games, 'game(s).')


def process_computer_choice():
    choice1 = random.randint(1,3)
    return choice1


def process_player_choice():
    print('What is your choice?')
    choice2 = (input())
    while choice2 != "1" and choice2 != "2" and choice2 != "3" and choice2 != "4":
        print("ERROR: the choice can only be 1, 2, 3, or 4.")
        choice2 = (input("Please enter a correct choice: "))
    return choice2


def determine_winner(player_choice, computer_choice):
    if computer_choice == 1:
        if player_choice == "2":
            print('Paper covers rock. You win!')
            winner = 'player'
        elif player_choice == "3":
            print("Rock crushes scissors. The computer wins!")
            winner = 'computer'
        else:
            print('The game is tied. Try again.')
            winner = 'tied'
    if computer_choice == 2:
        if player_choice == "1":
            print('Paper covers rock. The computer wins!')
            winner = 'computer'
        elif player_choice == "3":
            print("Scissors cuts paper. You win!")
            winner = 'player'
        else:
            print('The game is tied. Try again.')
            winner = 'tied'
    if computer_choice == 3:
        if player_choice == "1":
            print('Rock smashes scissors. You win!')
            winner = 'player'
        elif player_choice == "2":
            print("Scissors cuts paper. The computer wins!")
            winner = 'computer'
        else:
            print('The game is tied. Try again.')
            winner = 'tied'
    return winner

def display_menu():
    global tied_games
    global player_games
    global computer_games

    player_choice = 0

    while player_choice != "4":
        print('        MENU')
        print('1) Rock')
        print('2) Paper')
        print('3) Scissors')
        print('4) Quit')
        print("Let's play the game of Rock, Paper, Scissors.")
        computer_choice = process_computer_choice()
        player_choice = process_player_choice()

        if player_choice != "4":
            if computer_choice == 1:
                print('The computer chooses rock.')
            elif computer_choice == 2:
                print('The computer chooses paper.')
            else:
                print('The computer chooses scissors.')

            #display player choice
            if player_choice == "1":
                print('You choose rock.')
            elif player_choice == "2":
                print('You choose paper.')
            else:
                print('You choose scissors.')

            result = determine_winner(player_choice, computer_choice)
            if result == 'computer':
                computer_games += 1
            elif result == 'player':
                player_games += 1
            else:
                tied_games += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I believe that's all :)

Comment: Thank you so much man. Saved my ass. I didn't do it exactly like you did but this helped me understand what the hell was going on and where I was going wrong. Program functions perfectly now. Thanks again.

Comment: The code was purely to demonstrate the full 'corrections' I've noted, not to exactly to be copied / paste.

Comment: I didn't copy/paste it..... I just kept creating endless loops and seeing how you did it made me re-think my approach.

Answer (score 4):

Your program will run infinitely because you are not updating the variable `choice2` inside `display_menu()` function. What you are doing:

```
choice2 = 0
while choice2 != "4":
     # your code
     result = determine_winner(player_choice, computer_choice, choice2)
```

So, ultimately `choice2` is always 0 and your while loop keeps running endlessly.

**Edit**: You are returning a value from your `process_player_choice()` and assigning the value to a variable `player_choice` inside `display_menu()` function.

```
player_choice = process_player_choice()
```

I guess you should assign the return value to the variable `choice2` so that when user gives `4` as input, program will be terminated.

```
choice2 = process_player_choice()
```

**Note that**, you have another while loop inside `determine_winner()` which will run endlessly as well because of `choice2`. I believe that while loop is not required since you have a while loop already inside `display_menu()` function.

So, in short you actually don't need an additional variable `player_choice`, you just need one variable that will store the user choice and can be passed to required functions to execute their operations. You should also omit the while loop from the `display_menu()` function.

Lastly, as @AdrianoMartins mentioned in his answer, the following variables that you declared inside `display_menu()` should be global, otherwise you won't be able to access them from `main()` function.

```
number_of_tied_games = 0
number_of_player_games = 0
number_of_computer_games = 0
```

You can declare them in global scope and then declare them as global inside `display_menu()` to modify their value. For example:

```
// declaring globally
tied_games = 0
player_games = 0
computer_games = 0

def display_menu():
    // need to modify global copy of the variables
    global tied_games
    global player_games
    global computer_games
```

To learn more, i encourage you to see this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/423596/5352399).

Comment: What should I define choice2 as in display_menu...? It says choice2 is not defined when i try to run it but choice2 should be defined by process_player_choice

Comment: Thank you Sir for your help and time.